# Custom product template and action hooks in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a child theme from Storefront and have custom page templates running for the homepage and other pages without issues.

I am building a custom layout for Woocommerce pages and use `content-single-product.php` for the single product page with custom code in the file for example:

```
<div class="wc-product-images">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images'); ?>
</div>

<div class="wc-product-description">
    <?php the_content(); ?>     
</div>
```

*Question 1*: Do I call the Woocommerce Content correct with `do_action()` in the template file? I have a specific layout and cannot follow the hook layouts as per the default file

*Question 2*: When I call:

```
<?php 
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products' );
?>
```

I get the product description with the related products and actually need to build a div with only related products.

How can I call this properly without the description included?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making confusions, original `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' )` enables an entry point in woocommerce `content-single-product.php` template, where [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/3/) is used to hook other templates using the functions:

- `woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash()` *(with a hook priority of 10)*
- `woocommerce_show_product_images()` *(with a hook priority 20)*

So if you want to enable only the product image in your custom template you will have to create your own hook:

```
<div class="wc-product-images">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary_custom' ); ?>
</div>

<div class="wc-product-description">
    <?php the_content(); ?>     
</div>
```

Then you will add this in function.php file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary_custom', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
```

It should work as intended.

---

But you can use in your custom template the original hook, **if you don't need any different hook customizations**… In that case you will only have that:

```
<div class="wc-product-images">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' ); ?>
</div>

<div class="wc-product-description">
    <?php the_content(); ?>     
</div>
```

---

**Additon:** Related to your comment (regarding related products).

To enable related products in your custom template, add this block in it ***(with a custom hook)***:

```
<div class="wc-product-related">
    <?php do_action( 'custom_after_single_product_summary' ); ?>
</div>
```

Then you will add this in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme):

```
add_action( 'custom_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks will update the file as needed. What about woocommerce_output_related_products, I want to just show related products in a div with this. I can hide description via css if needed?